# How to download a file onclick then do history back?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to click on a link to download a file then go back to the previous page. I tried the code below, but it only downloads the file without going to previous page. Thank you.

```
<a href='/client.cfg' onclick='goBack()'>Download Config</a> 

<script type='text/javascript'>
function goBack() {            
  window.history.back();       
  window.location = document.referrer;
}
```

Comment: Wrong approach: instead, use the [download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) on your anchor tag

Comment: Thank you very much. It works with download attribute.